# Java looping to take away fractional numbers?

Tags: java

Hi I am doing a task in University and it asks me to *"Loop to print factorial numbers in reverse order starting from 9 down to 0."*

I was trying few ways to do it, but it just prints full numbers. The code is below.

I want to do the following:

> 9
>   8.9
>   8.8
>   8.7
>   8.6
>   ...
>   0

```
System.out.println("Loop to print factorial numbers in reverse order starting from 9 down to 0. ");  
int takeFraction = 11;
while (takeFraction > 1) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f" + takeFraction);
    System.out.println(System.out.printf);
    takeFraction = takeFraction - 0.1;
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: "factorial" !== "fractional". You need to look up the definition of "factorial;" you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: `takeFraction` is an int, so subtracting `0.1` will be the same as subtracting `1` in your case. (While you should get a compiler error because you are not typecasting)

Comment: Why is `takeFraction` an `int`?

Comment: Initialise `takeFraction` as `double` or `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You must change takeFraction to `double`, plus factorial != fractional. You should look what a factorial is. Here's a tip:

1! = 1.

2! = 2.

3! = 6.

4! = 24.

5! = 120.

Comment: just to add on something to the error list, `System.out.println(System.out.printf);` doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

```
double takeFraction = 9;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
while (takeFraction>0){ 
    System.out.println(df.format(takeFraction));
    takeFraction = takeFraction -0.1;            
}
```